# NodeJS How to wait for a function before closing the script

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I have to send a message with my **telegram bot** but I have to stop the code before executing

```js
consloe.log("You shouldn't see this text");
```

I can't send the message, instead, it is not a problem of the TelegramBot because if I remove `process.exit()` the message is sent successfully.

What should I do to send a message then close the code?

**My code:**

```js
const TelegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const token = 'xxxxx';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token);
bot.sendMessage(MyTelegramID, 'test');
process.exit()
console.log("You shouldn't see this text");
```

Comment: Is there any reason you *have* to use `process.exit()`? If you remove that and just let it run it works fine, as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendMessage` is an asynchronous function and it returns a promise. 
You should use `then` or `await`:

```
bot.sendMessage(MyTelegramID, 'test').then(() => { 
  process.exit();
  console.log("You shouldn't see this text");
});
```

or

```
(async () => {
  await bot.sendMessage(MyTelegramID, 'test');
  process.exit();
  console.log("You shouldn't see this text");
})();
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/api.md#telegrambotsendmessagechatid-text-options--promise)